# Character phases through wall one way, but not the other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm programming a simple 'game' that is just a block that can jump around. I placed a wall, but now the character phases through when moving to the right, but the collision works when going to the right.
Every other part of this is fine. the `willImpactMovingLeft` function works just fine and should be a mirror of `willImpactMovingRight`, but right doesn't work.
simple working code for this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div id="cube" class="cube"></div>
            <div id="ground1" class="ground1"></div>
            <div id="ground2" class="ground2"></div>
    <script>
var runSpeed = 5;var CUBE = document.getElementById("cube");var immovables = ["ground1", "ground2"];let Key = {pressed: {},left: "ArrowLeft",right: "ArrowRight",isDown: function (key){return this.pressed[key];},keydown: function (event){this.pressed[event.key] = true;},keyup: function (event){delete this.pressed[event.key];}}
        window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {Key.keyup(event);});
        window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {Key.keydown(event);});
        setInterval(()=>{
            if (Key.isDown(Key.left)){
                if(willImpactMovingLeft("cube", immovables)!=false){
                    cube.style.left = willImpactMovingLeft("cube", immovables)+"px";
                }else{
                    cube.style.left = CUBE.offsetLeft - runSpeed +"px";
                }
            }
            if (Key.isDown(Key.right)){
                if(willImpactMovingRight("cube", immovables)!=false){
                    cube.style.left = willImpactMovingRight("cube", immovables)+"px";
                }else{
                    cube.style.left = CUBE.offsetLeft + runSpeed +"px";
                }
            }
        }, 10);
        function willImpactMovingLeft(a, b){
            var docA = document.getElementById(a);
            var docB = document.getElementById(b[0]);
            for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
                docB = document.getElementById(b[i]);
                if((docA.offsetTop>docB.offsetTop&&docA.offsetTop<docB.offsetTop+docB.offsetHeight)||(docA.offsetTop+docA.offsetHeight>docB.offsetTop&&docA.offsetTop+docA.offsetHeight<docB.offsetTop+docB.offsetHeight)){//vertical check
                    if(docA.offsetLeft+docA.offsetWidth>docB.offsetLeft+runSpeed){
                        if(docA.offsetLeft-runSpeed<docB.offsetLeft+docB.offsetWidth){
                            return docB.offsetLeft+docB.offsetWidth;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        function willImpactMovingRight(a, b){
            var docA = document.getElementById(a);
            var docB = document.getElementById(b[0]);
            for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
                docB = document.getElementById(b[i]);
                if((docA.offsetTop>docB.offsetTop&&docA.offsetTop<docB.offsetTop+docB.offsetHeight)||(docA.offsetTop+docA.offsetHeight>docB.offsetTop&&docA.offsetTop+docA.offsetHeight<docB.offsetTop+docB.offsetHeight)){//vertical check
                    if(docA.offsetLeft>docB.offsetWidth+docB.offsetLeft-runSpeed){
                        if(docA.offsetLeft+docA.offsetWidth+runSpeed<=docB.offsetLeft){
                                CUBE.textContent = "WIMR";
                                return docB.offsetLeft-docA.offsetWidth;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script><style>.cube{height:50px;width:50px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:500px;left:500px;}.ground1{height:10px;width:100%;background-color:black;position:absolute;top:600px;left:0;}.ground2{height:150px;width:10px;background-color:black;position:absolute;top:450px;left:700px;}</style></body></html>
```

it looks like a lot, but the only problem is the last if statement. Even when the condition is true, it still skips the return number and returns false. Any idea why?

P.S. **I CANNOT USE THE CONSOLE, I AM ON A MANAGED COMPUTER**

Comment: The function either returns `false` or a number. It never returns `true`.

Comment: I didn't mean that the function returned true, I meant the if statement.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: sure, I'll try. give me a minute.

Comment: I'm new to this, should I put a link or paste it in somewhere

Comment: Paste it as text into your question.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to **minimal** example? Most of the code isn't necessary.

Comment: I've simplified it as much as possible while still keeping the problem expanded there. everything besides the function works fine and is only there to make the example functional.

Comment: It looks like your math is wrong. It's only possible for negative widths. How can  `docA.offsetLeft > docB.offsetWidth + docB.offsetLeft - runSpeed` and `docA.offsetLeft + docA.offsetWidth + runSpeed <= docB.offsetLeft` be true at the same time?

Comment: It's not a programming problem. It's a math problem. Don't try to solve the code. Solve the logic / algorithm with pen and paper.

Comment: you've got to be right; I need to work this out. thank you and have a great one.